# Azure Function inserting multiples data to Table Storage

Tags: azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am trying to insert in node multiples values to the Azure Storage Table but only the last value is added. Is it something related to node synchronous or asynchronous mode (I am newbie in node)?

```
    Code snippet:
```

...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) { 
    var emissao = newData[keys[i]].emissao;
    var codigoProduto = newData[keys[i]].codigoProduto;
    var quantidade = newData[keys[i]].quantidade;

    context.bindings.outputTable = {
        "PartitionKey": "08755044001539",
        "RowKey": i.toString(),
        "Emissao": emissao,
        "CodigoProduto": codigoProduto,
        "Quantidade": quantidade
    }
}

context.done();
```

project.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "outputTable",
      "tableName": "outTable",
      "connection": "detfunction9451_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you be adding records to the `outputTable`, instead?

```js
context.bindings.outputTable.push({
  "PartitionKey": "08755044001539",
  "RowKey": i.toString(),
  "Emissao": emissao,
  "CodigoProduto": codigoProduto,
  "Quantidade": quantidade
});
```

This may mean you have to initialize the `outputTable` first. I'm not sure. This may be necessary:

```js
context.bindings.outputTable = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) { 
  var emissao = newData[keys[i]].emissao;
  var codigoProduto = newData[keys[i]].codigoProduto;
  var quantidade = newData[keys[i]].quantidade;

  context.bindings.outputTable.push({
    "PartitionKey": "08755044001539",
    "RowKey": i.toString(),
    "Emissao": emissao,
    "CodigoProduto": codigoProduto,
    "Quantidade": quantidade
  });
}

context.done();
```

Here's an [example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#output---javascript-example).